# Least Square with Singular Matrix

Tags: matrices, least-squares

Suppose I have vector $x'=[1 $ $ $ $ x_2 $ $ $ $ x_3]$ and $x_3 = a + bx_2$ (where $a$ and $b$ are constant), and data, say $y$. In general, the least square will be $\beta = E[xx']^{-1}E[xy]$. Now, since $xx'$ is singular, how can I express the coefficient $\beta$?

From reading, I will need to find Moore-Penrose generalized inverse instead. However, I am not sure how this is done.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you addressing the problem of multilinear regression with collinearities ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though $xx'$ is necessarily singular, $E(xx')$ is generally positive definite.  If $E(xx')$ is not positive definite then $\beta$ is not *identified*.

Answer (score 0):

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a nonzero vector $v$ is
$$
 v^{+} = \frac{v^{*}}{v^{*} v}.
$$
See [Laub](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot91/), example 4.8, p. 31.

To compute the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$, find the singular value decomposition:
$$
 \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U} 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right]
\mathbf{V}^{*}
$$
The pseudoinverse is constructed using the prescription
$$
  \mathbf{A}^{+} = \mathbf{V} 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \mathbf{S}^{-1} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{array} \right]
\mathbf{U}^{*}
$$